# Is it OK to delete related records in model? Doesnt it hurt SRP?

Tags: multithreading, single-responsibility-principle

there is a ForumThread and ForumPost model classes, forum posts belongs to a thread. If I delete a thread, all their post should go, so, in pseudo code:

```
class ForumThread::delete (ID)
  DELETE FROM forumpost WHERE thread_id = 1;
  DELETE FROM thread WHERE id = 1;
```

but isn't the first SQL at the wrong place? now ForumThread::delete does more than it should. But where to put it, to controller? In this case, there is an opportunity to accientally delete a thread without deleting its posts too

Comment: Doesnt a foreign key solve this problem?

Comment: and if Im using MyISAM? :)

Comment: Transactionality is separate from single responsibility. An interesting question is perhaps whether your model should care about the underlying persistence implementation.